# Subsequence and integers as a sum of $\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For all $M \in \mathbb{Z}$, is there a finite sequence of positive integers $(n_i)_{i \in I}$, s.t. $\sum_{i \in I} \frac{1}{n_i} = M$, and there is no subsequence $(n_i)_{i \in J}$ of $(n_i)_{i \in I}$ such that $\sum_{i \in J} \frac{1}{n_i}$ is an integer ?

For a related question see,

[Integers as a sum of $\frac{1}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327001/integers-as-a-sum-of-frac1n)

Comment: Do you require the $n_i$ to be distinct?

Comment: No. That would even be a harder question.

Comment: Now posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/209958/subsequence-and-integers-as-a-sum-of-frac1n